# How to show custom picklist value in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to show a custom dropdown list. I have built some code, but output isn't coming as expected. I have added the output screenshot in the attachment.

Requiremnt :
 2 Custom Object : `MyObject__c (Fields:MPG_Code__c, Price__c)` and `MyObject_Config__c(Fields : MPG_Code__c)`. Both objects share a common field(`MPG_Code__c`)

My requirement is to show all `price__c` of MyObject__c available for that `MPG_code__c` in a dropdown.

**Apex:**

```
public class PriceGroupConfigControllerExt {

    public final MyObject_Config__c myObj {get; private set;} 
    ApexPages.StandardController stdController;
    public list<SelectOption> pickList {get; private set;}
    public String selectedId {get; set;}

public PriceGroupConfigControllerExt(ApexPages.StandardController Controller) {  

        stdController = Controller;                
        this.myObj = (MyObject_Config__c)stdController.getRecord(); 

    List<MyObject__c> mpgList = [Select Id, MPG_Code__c,Price__c                                
                                 From MyObject__c 
                                 Where MPG_Code__c =: myObj.MPG_Code__c 
                                ];  

    if (pickList == null) {
            pickList = new list<SelectOption>();
        }

        SelectOption firstOption = new SelectOption('', ' - Select Discount price' + ' -');
        pickList.add(firstOption);
        for MyObject__c mpgObj : mpgList) {
                this.pickList.add(new SelectOption(mpgObj.id,string.valueOf(mpgObj.Price__c)));
        }
}
```

**Visualforce page:**

```
<apex:outputLabel>Specific Discount</apex:outputLabel>
   <apex:selectList id="discountPrice" value="{!selectedId}" >
<apex:selectOptions value="{!pickList}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

**OutPut :** 
 [image]

Comment: I can't see an error description? What is wrong with that picklist?

Comment: In the actual code have you changed mpgcObj to myObj? The code you have posted doesn't look like it would compile.

Comment: @mast0r : All the values of Picklist should come as a dropdown. But Here all the values are coming differently. In the image I have posted the output.

Comment: @KeithC : Yes In the actual code I have changed the code to myObj. It was a typing mistake.

Still same error is coming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need add one more paramether to your list. Try `size="1"` in your `apex:selectList`

Comment: And maybe `multiselect="false"`

Comment: Mayby... But I don't think it will be required.

Comment: Yes `multiselect="false"` isn't required as it has picklist datatype not multi Picklist datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Artur. Here is the solution. We only have to add `Size='1'`

```
<apex:selectList id="discountPrice" value="{!selectedId}" size="1" >
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!pickList}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```